# Need whirl/swirl/twirl shader for Unity 4.6 free version

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

For my game I need a whirl/swirl/twirl shader to distort pictures. I'm using the free version of Unity 4.6. I found some code on the internet (http://www.geeks3d.com/20110428/shader-library-swirl-post-processing-filter-in-glsl/) but have no idea how I can use this inside Unity.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You cannot do post processing in unity free. You need pro.

Comment: Thank you. I have a shader for a pixelated effect working in the free version. If that is possible why can't I have a whirl effect?